# The difference between QDataStream and QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

```
QTemporaryFile tf;
tf.open ();
QDataStream tfbs (&tf);
tfbs << "hello\r\n" << "world!\r\n";
const int pos = int (tf.pos ());

QByteArray ba;
ba.append ("hello\r\n");
ba.append ("world!\r\n");
const int size = ba.size ();
```

Basically my question is, what am I doing wrong? Why is pos > size? Should I not be using << ? Should I not be using QDataStream?

Edit: Is there a way to configure QDataStream or QTemporaryFile so that the << operator doesn't prepend strings with 32bit lengths and store the null terminators in the file? Calling QDataStream::writeBytes when I just have a series of quoted strings and QStrings makes for very ugly code.

Comment: It might be helpful if you were to indicate what `pos` and `size` actually are.

Comment: pos == 25, size == 15

Comment: the first is a stream, the second is an array, they serve completely different purposes and often are used together

Comment: I know the serve different purposes. I'm just trying to understand why by temp file is bigger than expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the docs. I'm not going to go over QByteArray, as I believe it's fairly obvious that it is working as expected.

The QDataStream operator<<(char*) overload evaluates to [the writeBytes() function](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html#writeBytes).

This function outputs:

> Writes the length specifier len and the buffer s to the stream and
>   returns a reference to the stream. The len is serialized as a quint32,
>   followed by len bytes from s. Note that the data is not encoded.

So for `"hello\r\n"`, I would expect the output to be:

```
0,0,0,8,'h','e','l','l','o','\r','\n',0
```

The 4-byte length, followed by the bytes from the string. The string-ending NULL is probably also being added to the end, which would account for the otherwise mysterious extra two bytes.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. Wish there was a standard cleaner way to write strings to a temp file

Comment: @cppguy - maybe with QTextStream?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm writing strings and then a large QByteArray. I was hoping for something that handled all of those cases

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up writing my own helper class to serialize my data:

```
class QBinaryStream
{
public:
    QBinaryStream (QIODevice& iod) : m_iod (iod) {}
    QBinaryStream& operator << (const char* data)
    {
        m_iod.write (data);
        return *this;
    }
    QBinaryStream& operator << (const QString& data)
    {
        return operator << (data.toUtf8 ());
    }
    QBinaryStream& operator << (const QByteArray& data)
    {
        m_iod.write (data);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    QIODevice& m_iod;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> Should I not be using QDataStream?

In your case maybe `QTextStream` or even `QString` would do.

> The QTextStream class provides a convenient interface for reading and
>   writing text.
>
> QTextStream can operate on a QIODevice, a QByteArray or a QString.
>   Using QTextStream's streaming operators, you can conveniently read and
>   write words, lines and numbers.

As for `QByteArray`, `Qstring` should be preferred to it whenever possible

> The QByteArray class provides an array of bytes.
>
> QByteArray can be used to store both raw bytes (including '\0's) and
>   traditional 8-bit '\0'-terminated strings. Using QByteArray is much
>   more convenient than using const char *. Behind the scenes, it always
>   ensures that the data is followed by a '\0' terminator, and uses
>   implicit sharing (copy-on-write) to reduce memory usage and avoid
>   needless copying of data.
>
> In addition to QByteArray, Qt also provides the QString class to store
>   string data. For most purposes, QString is the class you want to use.
>   It stores 16-bit Unicode characters, making it easy to store
>   non-ASCII/non-Latin-1 characters in your application. Furthermore,
>   QString is used throughout in the Qt API. The two main cases where
>   QByteArray is appropriate are when you need to store raw binary data,
>   and when memory conservation is critical (e.g., with Qt for Embedded
>   Linux).